# Gradle on Mac installed using MacPorts: where is Gradle home?

Tags: macos, gradle, macports

I installed Gradle using MacPorts and now I am unable to find where the Gradle home is. For example Eclipse asks me for the location and I have no idea:

[image: Eclipse asking me for Gradle home]

I tried specifying the path obtained from `which gradle`:

```
$ which gradle
/opt/local/bin/gradle
```

But it does not work. So, where is the Gradle home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that MacPorts tells you the Gradle home when installing / upgrading Gradle. The installation log ends with the following:

```
--->  Some of the ports you installed have notes:
  gradle has the following notes:
    Remember to set the environment variable GRADLE_HOME 
    to the path to the gradle distribution:
    /opt/local/share/java/gradle
```

So the correct Gradle home in that case is:

```
/opt/local/share/java/gradle
```

And this works in the Eclipse scenario mentioned above.